# Problem with odbc connection by usage .Net 5 OdbcConnection in application on Linux environment

Tags: c#, .net, linux, oracle, odbc

I have a problem in .Net 5 application with setup connection to ORACLE 12g database by usage of System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection. Initially this application was developed on .Net Core 3 and was used on Windows environment only, now I ported it to .Net 5 and trying to test it on Linux environment.

Here is problematic part of the code:

```
using (OdbcConnection pmConnection = new OdbcConnection($"DSN={fOdbcName};UID={fLogin};PWD=fPwd};Integrated Security=no;"))
{
try
{
pmConnection.Open();
...
}
...
}
```

This code is being executed OK when application is running on WinSrv2019 environment.
But when application runs on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, then at the moment of execution pmConnection.Open() the application throws exception:

```
ORIGINATOR: clOdbcReceiver: Exception on attempt to test connection to ODBC data source EIFULL. Connection string used: DSN=EIFULL;UID=<hidden>;PWD=<hidden>;Integrated Security=no;.
EXCEPTION HEADER:
ERROR [08004] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
EXCEPTION STACK TRACE:
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionHandle..ctor(OdbcConnection connection, OdbcConnectionString constr, OdbcEnvironmentHandle environmentHandle)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionOpen..ctor(OdbcConnection outerConnection, OdbcConnectionString connectionOptions)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
```

On Ubuntu server following prerequisites are done:

- Installed packages:
- oracle-instantclient12.2-basic-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
- oracle-instantclient12.2-odbc-12.2.0.1.0-2.x86_64.rpm
- oracle-instantclient12.2-sqlplus-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
- Configured environment variables ORACLE_HOME, TNS_ADMIN
- Installed ODBC driver manager unixODBC
- Configured database in tnsnames.ora
- Configured ODBC driver in odbcinst.ini Configured DSN on odbc.ini

Configuration seems OK, because when I try to connect to the ODBC driver from PuTTY with the command
`isql EIFULL <login> <password>`, then connection to Oracle via ODBC driver is successfully established (so unixODBC knows the location of tnsnames.ora and can resolve DSN).

This is my first experience to port .Net application from Windows to Linux environment. I spent few hours trying to find in Internet something about similar issue, but with no success.
My question is: does anybody have successful experience with usage of .Net Core OdbcConnection on Linux environment to setup connection to Oracle?
If someone had the same issue and solved it, I would be appreciate for hints about the solution.
As I didn't find something relevant in Internet on this topic now I have suspicion, that OdbcConnection is not compatible with unixODBC driver manager and have some doubts is it worth spending further time trying to troubleshoot this issue or better to try to consider alternative workarounds.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the ODBC provider instead of [ODP.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core/)?

Comment: Hi @madreflection , I just tried shortly your idea with usage of ODP.NET instead of connection via ODBC. The first result is OK: direct connection to Oracle is successfully established with application running on both Windows and Linux environments. So, I am going to change code with this replacement, hopefully will not get regression. Thank you so much for that idea!